# In Websphere, how do I change the page I get redirected to when a user enters an invalid url?

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, websphere, e-commerce

As of now, if I directly type into the address bar `https://my.website.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/null` I get redirected to a particular error page, because obviously that page is not going to exist.

However, I would like to to have this url route to a completely different custom error page (I already have the jsp for it), but I have no idea where that configuration is in WebSphere.  How can I change the page that this redirects me to?  Is this some sort of Struts configuration?

Comment: The action--or page--associated with a "page not found" error, are set with the HTTP server living below your Websphere application server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the error page for HTTP status code 404 in yor web.xml.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/yourErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

This can be set on application level.